# iOS 9: cannot open the page when launch the local ios app by browser

Tags: ios, web, web-applications, safari, mobile-safari

```
  if (isIos) {
        if (isIos9) {
                window.location = 'bdwm://';
                iosGo();
            } else {
                createIframe();
                iosGo();
         }
    }

  function createIframe() {
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.style.cssText = 'display:none;width:0;height:0';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.src = 'bdwm://';
    }

  function iosGo() {
        var t = Date.now();
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (Date.now() - t < 600) {
                location.href = "https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/....."//the iOS app url
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```

---

I want to solve this question "*when exists your app on your iPhone, you can first launch the local your app,but when not exists, you must go to download the iOS app*".

The above is my code. When in iOS 9.3, the app will alert the dialog "*cannot open the page because the address is invalid*", how can i solve it?

[image]

Comment: What's that bdwm:// protocol? That could be the point.

Comment: yeah,it the scheme protocal!But it doesn't work!